# Compound Key to Relationship

Tags: arcobjects, c#, arcgis-engine

If tableField = "Process ID" and layerField = "PID" then this works:

```
IRelationshipClass relationshipClass =
    memoryRelationshipFactory.Open(
    "Join",
    table as IObjectClass,
    tableField,
    geoFeatureLayer.DisplayFeatureClass as IObjectClass,
    layerField,
    "forward",
    "backward",
    esriRelCardinality.esriRelCardinalityOneToOne );
```

If tableField = "Process ID, Year Made" and layerField = "PID, YM" then it fails.

(Table is SQL Server table.)

I have tried brackets and quotes to no effect. Is it possible to pass a compound key?